# get id of the node with maximum value

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath

i have something like this

```
 <ValueSet>
    <value id="0">109.3</value>
    <value id="1">110.6</value>
    <value id="2">111.1</value>
    <value id="3">111.5</value>
 </ValueSet>
```

and i need the id of the node that has the maximum value,
i need do this in javascript using Xpath.

i do this:

```
var path = "//ValueSet[not(value <= preceding-sibling::ValueSet/value) and " +
           "           not(value <= following-sibling::ValueSet/value)]";
var result = this.documentRoot.evaluate(path, this.documentRoot, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
alert("max:" + result.textContent);
```

but doesn't work, :(

Comment: What's your code so far?

Comment: i edit it with the code that i try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use**:

**`/*/value[not(. < ../value)]/@id`**

**Be ready to get more than one node**, because there might be several nodes with the maximum value.

Comment: @voodoomsr: Was my answer usefult to you?